# move master page from development to production

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

We are planning to change the user interface of our Sharepoint 2010 site collection. This involves changes in style sheets and the master pages.
We got dev/uat/prd site collections, where we got full control, but we are not sharepoint admins.
So, what we need is a safe way of moving the new master page and style sheets from our /dev site collection to /uat and later to /prd without affecting the content on those site collections. The solutions, that I found so far require server-level rights, but we need something that we can do ourselves, staying within the limits of a site collection owner, with Designer only, so no powershell, no VS.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have site collection level access there are few alternatives:

1. Use SharePoint Designer to Import new files over the old ones one Site Collection at a time
2. Map _catalogs/masterpage folder as network share and copy the files using Windows Explorer one Site Collection at a time
3. If there are too many Site Collections for manually doing the work, then best is probably be to write PowerShell script that copies the file to each Site Collection

Comment: Thanks, so in general, is it safe to export this and other files, like style sheets from the _style library or data sources from the fpdatasources library and copy to the production environment?

Comment: "fpdatasources" I cannot comment on as I haven't used those that much, but style sheets, javascript files, master pages, page layouts are usually copy&pasteable without issues assuming environments are at least approximately on same patch level. But always TAKE BACKUPS of files before overwriting, and remember to Check-In and Publish files if versioning is enabled.

Comment: Ok, thank you, well, all of them is on the same server, only different site collections. Direct copy from the masterpage folder doesn't work for me (I get file not found error when I try to copy anything from this folder), but the export-import from Designer works goed.